# How to build dnscrypt plugins?

Tags: compiling, cmake

I tried to build a plugin for DNSCrypt, but it keeps telling me that it needs some other files.

I need to know how I can build it, and I've never compiled a package from scratch.  I've always been able to use a repository.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) with gcc on [CodeAnywhere](https://codeanywhere.com/)

Here is the link to the plugin: [GeoIP Plugin](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-plugin-geoip-block)

Here is the link to dnscrypt: [DNSCrypt](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/)

Here is what I get when I try to compile:

```
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$ cmake . && make                                                                                                            
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/cabox/workspace" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.                                                           
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.                                                                                           
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$ cd plugin                                                                                                                  
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace/plugin$ cmake . && make                                                                                                     
-- Configuring done                                                                                                                                            
-- Generating done                                                                                                                                             
-- Build files have been written to: /home/cabox/workspace/plugin                                                                                              
[100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/geoip-block.dir/geoip-block.c.o                                                                                            
/home/cabox/workspace/plugin/geoip-block.c:14:29: fatal error: dnscrypt/plugin.h: No such file or directory                                                    
 #include <dnscrypt/plugin.h>                                                                                                                                  
                             ^                                                                                                                                 
compilation terminated.                                                                                                                                        
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/geoip-block.dir/geoip-block.c.o] Error 1                                                                                              
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/geoip-block.dir/all] Error 2                                                                                                          
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If more info is needed, I will add it as soon as possible.

---

Dnscrypt build was all fine but i still get
http://pastebin.com/MeU4Q24W

Comment: I'm writing an answer, but I'm a slow typer.  Just hang on

Comment: Answer is Finished.  If you have any questions, please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

It looks like terdon added and updated some commands over the Thanksgiving Holiday.  These add extra and or needed functionality.  I want to thank him for adding these.

### Task

First, let's start with a clean slate.

```
cd ~ && rm -Rv workspace
```

Now, we make sure we have the right tools for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update  ## run make sure you get all things right
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt-get install cmake wget software-properties-common python-software-properties autoconf
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shnatsel/dnscrypt
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maxmind/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libtool openssl libssl-dev
```

Then, in case you want a package in Source Control, we need to add more tools.  DNScrypt doesn't need it, but in case you ever build an item from source again:

```
sudo apt-get install cvs subversion git-core mercurial
```

You should be in your home directory, so now we need the actual source tarball for dnscrypt-proxy:

- Download the [libsodium](http://doc.libsodium.org/) (if you don't have it installed)

  ```
  wget https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.1.tar.gz
  tar xzf libsodium-1.0.1.tar.gz && cd libsodium-1.0.1 && ./configure
  make && make check && sudo make install
  sudo ldconfig && ./configure && cd ..
  ```
- Download the [geoip api](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/downloadable/) (if you don't have it installed)

  ```
  wget https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-c/archive/v1.6.3.tar.gz
  tar xzf v1.6.3.tar.gz && cd geoip-api-c-1.6.3
  sh bootstrap && ./configure
  make && make check && sudo make install && cd ..
  ```
- Download the [ldns](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/ldns/) (if you don't have it installed)

  ```
  wget http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/downloads/ldns/ldns-1.6.17.tar.gz
  tar xzf ldns-1.6.17.tar.gz && cd ldns-1.6.17
  ./configure && make && sudo make install && cd ..
  ```
- Download the [DNSCrypt-Proxy Version 1.4.1 Tar.bz2](http://download.dnscrypt.org/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy-1.4.1.tar.bz2) File.  For the Ubuntu Way, add this [DNSCrypt-PPA](https://launchpad.net/~shnatsel/+archive/ubuntu/dnscrypt)  **Please note, that this PPA is dated (the most recent version is 1.4.0 for 13.10), therefore we will install from source**

  ```
  tar -xvjpf dnscrypt-proxy-1.4.1.tar.bz2 && cd dnscrypt-proxy-1.4.1
  ./configure && make && sudo make install
  ```

  - Since we deleted Plugin, we need to [redownload the Zip File From the GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-plugin-geoip-block/archive/master.zip).  The directory we create will be called master

    `sudo apt-get install zip unzip` Tar won't extract zips, so we need new tools.  You may already have these.

    `unzip master.zip && cd master`
  - Once you unzipped the file go to the folder and edit `CMakeLists.txt` and add this lines

> include_directories(/home/cabox/workspace/dnscrypt-proxy-1.4.1/src/include)
>       include_directories(/home/cabox/workspace/geoip-api-c-1.6.3/libGeoIP)
>       include_directories(/home/cabox/workspace/ldns-1.6.17/ldns)

- Then, run

  ```
  cmake . && make
  cd .. && cp -v master/nameofplugin.ext /some/dir/where/you/store/plugins
  ```

---

### Why Your Error is Occurring

The Header File for DNSCrypt `plugin.h` is only installed in `/usr/include/dnscrypt` after you sucessfully compile DNSCrypt itself.  You couldn't compile DNSCrypt for two Reasons:

1. You did not have the source tarball.
2. [Cross-Make, or CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) for short is an independent Build system that doesn't use the standard Linux Build Process.  Clients that use it include KDE,and Poppler.

---

### References

1. [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org) User.  We build from Source routinely.  Every update, in fact.
2. The Ubuntu [EasyCompilingHOWTO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)

Comment: Let me know if it worked....

Comment: i Will didn't got the chance to login to the CodeAnywhere as soon as i checked it i will let you know

Comment: Great, I look forward to a response....

Comment: well look what get i posted the output

Comment: It looks as if you need to build the plugin inside the DNSCrypt Directory.  Unzip master.zip inside the DNSCrypt Directory.

Comment: Oh that's a good idea i will try it

Comment: There is a way to set the path for included files in cmake how can i do that?

Comment: I think [this tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/) may help better than I can.  See Adding a Version Number and Configured Header File

Comment: Also i am making the commands in to bash script so everyone who comes here can use it

Comment: Ok that was all needed files and info to build it :)