# LD_LIBRARY_PATH always blank after sudo

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, shared-library

I get shared library errors whenever I seem to install software manually. Upon executing `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it shows up as.. *nothing*. I've tried adding `/usr/local/lib` to a `.conf` file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` but it seems like it never executes.

This doesn't work, either (quotes or otherwise):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sudo ldconfig -v
```

The value will be set temporarily, but it will not retain the value if I so much as exit a terminal window. Rebooting does nothing, either.

Comment: Try adding it to `~/.bashrc`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make \`sudo\` preserve $PATH?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path)

Comment: It's not a duplicate; the question is irrelevant and the answer doesn't work.

Comment: It's a [bad Idea to install software from source on a binary system](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152258/using-awesome-window-manager-on-centos-7/152809#152809)!!!  Use your Package Manager, [unless there is no other way](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169255/how-to-build-dnscrypt-plugins/169272#169272)

Comment: Yes, let me use *broken software from a year ago* instead of allowing me to update it to test if anything has changed for the better.

Comment: First of all, before blowing up at me, read my first link, the consider reading the second, since you want the package.  Third, why don't you tell me what you are trying to update, and I'll help you do it properly.  Exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is also bad, because if not done properly, you break the path your binary packages expect.  This problem is your 3rd comment to Kevdog777

Comment: I'm being very cautious and meticulous about the changes being made. I'm only considering making this change because it's documented *everywhere* as being a generally good idea. As for what's being updated: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171270/openconnect-not-resolving-hostnames

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
vim ~/.bashrc

...
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

This will let you restart your computer, and still have that path assigned.

Comment: That's fine for one user. What about for *all* users?

Comment: @DissidentRage: add the same to /etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because this works for the given scope. What can I do about the files that are clearly not being run in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`?

Answer (score 2):

I finally resolved this with an alias:

```
alias sudo='sudo PATH="$PATH" HOME="$HOME" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"'
```

Be sure to use single quotes, so that the variables are expanded at the time of invocation, not at the time the alias is defined.

This:

- preserves HOME (which otherwise gets set to /root)
- preserves PATH (which otherwise gets set to a 'safe' path in suders)
- preserves the *current* value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH (which otherwise gets blanked)

(You can see what things get set to with: `sudo bash -c "echo $HOME"`)

I am working with custom drivers and always have to sudo my test programs to access the driver. I don't want to install test versions of libraries in the system area, so I use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to setup a specific test directory as needed. I cant just set a fixed LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I need to be able to change it and keep the current setting. Preserving PATH and HOME gives me access to my work environment - scripts and directory structure.

This alias avoids having to grant blanket permissions in sudoers... and there is apparently no workaround for LD_LIBRARY_PATH regardless of sudoers settings anyway. It does not work sudo inside of scripts, but those can be hardcoded as needed.

Answer (score 1):

On Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6, `/etc/ld.so.conf` contains `include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`. Without this line, items in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` would never be parsed.

To see which libraries / directories `ldconfig` is parsing

```
ldconfig -v
```

> Print current version number, the name of each directory as it is scanned, and any links that are created.

Comment: Yeah, I checked `/etc/ld.so.conf` earlier as I was curious what it contained. It did have the `include` line.

Comment: Running `ldconfig -v` might give you an idea why the library isn't being included. You can run `ldconfig -p` to print the libraries and directories that are in the current cache file.