# OpenConnect not resolving hostnames

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, networkmanager

I'm running LMDE 17, and I've installed OpenConnect v6 and the repository version of network-manager-openconnect. Everything is peachy, except any address for the domain `companyname.local` doesn't resolve in a browser (this was no problem in Windows using Cisco AnyConnect). I can use SVN, and view internal versions of public domains, but internal ones just don't resolve.

I've used (and rolled back) the updated [vpnc-script](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/vpnc-script.html) file but that didn't seem to make any difference. I've seen some suggestions on making changes at the server level. I am in no position to do so.

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have an `/etc/hosts` file.  If so, try adding `companyname.local` and it's IP address to the file.

Comment: I do have `/etc/hosts` but I don't know its IP address.

Comment: Can you ping Companyname.local on a Windows machine?

Comment: I can, and it works for one subdomain, but different subdomains are routed to different IP addresses. To do that I would have to create my own table...

Comment: For each subdomain, you need to configure the VPN script, or if your private IP address is on the same domain as your company's private IP addresses, you can add each subdomain to `/etc/hosts`.  I'm looking at options now.

Comment: In your Script, are `INTERNAL_IP4_DNS` and `INTERNAL_IP4_NBNS` set?

Comment: The former is referenced but never altered. The latter doesn't show up beyond the initial comments.

Comment: Well I have a hunch that the WINS Server needs to be set to resolve the Intranet Pages.  `NBNS` is the Abbreviation for NetBios NameServer, aka WINS.  On Windows during the Negotiation Phase all these servers are passed to the VPN adapter.  On your OpenConnect they are never passed.

Comment: I.. don't know what this means. Is this something I can't resolve on my end?

Comment: In your Script, where you set the DNS Servers add the variable `INTERNAL_IP4_NBNS` and set it to the value you retrieve by performing an `ipconfig /all` in the WINS Server Values.

Comment: If this is the fix, this is beyond my skills as I am at best an absolute beginner in shell scripting.

Answer (score 5):

You may be running into [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=783569).

If you're stuck on an older version of Network Manager, try the following workaround (taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/852460/150936), but also found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/634446/174220)).

> 1. Open `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` in an editor with root rights.
> 2. Delete (or comment out with a dash `#`) the line that reads `dns=dnsmasq` .
> 3. Restart NetworkManager via `sudo service NetworkManager restart` .

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar experience and concluded that the interaction and scripting with Cisco AnyConnect was adding DNS hosts dynamically.

On a Debian-based distro such as yours (I am on Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca), I found that installing [network-manager-openconnect-gnome](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openconnect) provided a helpful configuration interface for DNS parameters and the like, and provides a very smooth integration in Linux Mint anyway, right down to task-tray widgets/status.

`sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome`

Then add a VPN connection, and under IPv4/IPv6 tabs, add the DNS servers that you find AnyConnect is adding.  There's a number of ways to do that - you can just use Wireshark to look at your DNS queries if unsure.  You should be able to capture a couple of primary/secondary servers.  You need to add these in IP-address form to the VPN config.

You should also consider establishing what your DNS search-domains are under AnyConnect, and adding those manually to OpenConnect config via NetworkManager - this is another auto-setting that does not get applied.  You may find that in places your system relies on short/non-domain-qualified hostnames in places, so you will need the search domain suffixes.

[image: add VPN OpenConnect]
[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem (via command-line `sudo openconnect ...` it DID resolve DNS, via UI didn't). Adding the DNS servers worked on my problem too!

Comment: Unfortunately I am not as lucky. Adding DNS servers did not resolve my issue. Like  @morhook it also works for me using `sudo openconnect ...`.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with the same issue. To get NetBIOS look ups working, edit your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and add "wins" to the "hosts:" line.

example:

```
hosts: files dns wins
```

Next, edit your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file and add/edit the `wins server =` line to add your WINS server. FYI, Samba will not act as a server and a client, so if you have `wins support = yes`, you will need to disable it or configure it to work with OpenConnect.

Comment: And if I don't know the location of the WINS server?

Comment: @DissidentRage I've had the same problem and found a solution. Take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/a/126527/209890

Answer (score 1):

I also found the same problem, I keep playing around with network-manager-openconnect-gnome until the connection started to work.
The winning step for me was to **disable IPv6** for the VPN.